# reverse engineering не могу найти нужные строки

Tags: reverse-engineering

Пытаюсь разобрать crackme с сайта crackmes https://www.crackmes.one/crackme/65c4021aeef082e477ff688a ,
но никак не могу найти строки, например "Enter the PIN :". Не первый раз с этим сталкиваюсь. Бывали файлы, в которых также не мог найти строки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это связано? И как с этим бороться?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.